# How to reply to an invitation?

Tags: english-to-german

How can I reply to a friend that invited me to her birthday party asking when is it and where?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific: 1) What do you already know and what have you found? 2) What exactly do you want to convey? 3) What kind of tone do you aspire?

Answer (score 1):

There are some phrases which are common in German:

Asking for the **time**:

> Um welche Uhrzeit findet die Geburtstagsfeier statt?
>
> Zu welcher Uhrzeit möchtest du feiern?
>
> Wann beginnt die Geburtstagsfeier?

or more colloquial:

> Wann feierst du deinen Geburtstag?

---

Asking for the **place**:

> An welchem Ort findet die Geburtstagsfeier statt?
>
> Wo findet die Geburtstagsfeier statt?

or more colloquial:

> Wo feierst du deinen Geburtstag?

Comment: In the real world nobody sais "Um welche Uhrzeit..." or "Zu welcher Uhrzeit". Did you find this in a textbook? Not the best one, it seems...

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking to a friend, I suggest that you say something like:
"Danke für die Einladung!  Wann und wo?  Ich freu mich schon!" (Emphasis on "freu" in the last sentence!)

Answer (score 1):

Here are real-world dialogues:

> A: Hallo B., schön dich zu sehen. Du, darf ich dich zu meiner Geburtstagsfeier einladen am Samstag?
>
> B: Hey, super, ja, danke! Wann geht's denn los?
>
> A: So ab 7 oder so.

Or:

> B: Ja, klar, sehr gern. Wann soll ich kommen?

Or:

> B: Oh, gerne. Um wieviel Uhr?

Or if the conversation is via e-mail:

> A: Lieber B, am Freitag habe ich Geburtstag. Gefeiert wird am Samstag. Darf ich dich dazu einladen? Ich würde mich freuen, mit dir und noch ein paar Freunden zusammen zu feiern.
>
> B: Liebe A, vielen Dank für die Einladung. Natürlich komme ich da gerne. Wann soll es denn losgehen?

Answer (score 0):

> »Danke für die Einladung, kommen kann ich nicht – ich weiß weder wann
>   noch wohin!«